# How do I trigger on every INSERT action in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am using Typeorm in my API. The problem is `afterInsert` in subscriber hooks are triggered before the transaction is committed. That's because it does not rely on DB by ORM itself. It prohibits me to access the data record in everything that happens in the hook because the transaction is still pending. Would you give me any advice on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use an external event broker.

You push to a broker in your subscriber code, for instance Redis queue, Rabbitmq, aws SQS or kinesis, kafka...

You listen to the queue in another code, at this point your first transaction should have been commited. You will work on a separate transaction and can implement your subscriber code that can rely on the commited data of the first transaction.

If the commit of the first transaction is very long, then using a typeorm subscriber won't work as even with an event broker you have no guarantee that the transaction is commited. So then you can just add code to push in the broker after the transaction is finished, or relying on sql triggers that can push in an event broker, or implementing a retry system based on the version column of typeorm so you are sure that the update was commited, works best with event brokers where retrying is free such as kafka or SQS.